# CPT Rewrite Slug to Another CPT Slug/Key (as CPT-A/CPT-B Format)

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

I registered multiple custom post types with following pattern:

- CPT-A: `'has_archive'=> 'cpt-a'` and `'rewrite'=> array('slug' => 'cpt-a', 'with_front'=> true)`
- CPT-B: `'has_archive'=> 'cpt-a/cpt-b'` and `'rewrite'=> array('slug' => 'cpt-a/cpt-b', 'with_front'=> true)`
- CPT-C: `'has_archive'=> 'cpt-a/cpt-c'` and `'rewrite'=> array('slug' => 'cpt-a/cpt-c', 'with_front'=> true)`

**Here the slug of CPT-A is the base for all other CPTs slugs.**

The archives are working fine.  *WP generates the Single Post permalink according to the rewrite slug, however, it throws 404 on frontend.*

- I flushed the permalinks.
- I tried to replace the slug with placeholder and then adding the value dynamically via `post_link` and `post_type_link` filter. - however this seemed to unnecessary or I didn't get the purpose of doing it when WP was able to generate-only the link as desired already.
- It also works fine if I remove everything after the slash in rewrite slugs such as instead of `cpt-a/cpt-b`, I tried with `cpt-a` or random text for the `cpt-b` slug. It worked but that's not what I'm looking for.

**#1: What I'm missing?**

**Rewrite rules?** If yes, how can I add something generic like for all CPTs wherever is the %post_type_key% placeholder in the permalink, it get replaced with current post's post type key.

**Or can't we direct WP to use 'has_archive' value** (which may have one more slashed string or URL base) for slug too just as WP does it for 'feeds' which are set to has_archive value by default.

**#2: Will it impact performance since I'll be having 20+ CPTs and all require this custom rewrite slug.**

---

**UPDATE: Explanation with another Example:**

- CPT-A: `events` (post type `key` is `events`, `has_archive` value is also `events`, and `rewrite slug` (url base) for its post permalinks is also `events`
- CPT-B: `webinars` (post type `key` is `webinars` **but** `has_archive` value is `events/webinars` and `rewrite slug` for its post permalinks is also `events/webinars`
- CPT-C: `on-demand` (key: `on-demand`, **but** has_archive: `events/on-demand`, rewrite slug: `events/on-demand`)
- **Archives of all CPTs are working i-e:** /events, /events/webinars, and /events/on-demand - these are all working.
- **Single posts** of CPT-A (`events`) are also working i-e: /events/post-title-in-events-posttype
- **Single posts** of other CPTS such as `webinars` and `on-demand` are not working since they i-e: /events/webinars/post-title-in-*webinars* etc. here `events/webinars` is the rewrite slug (url base) of `webinars` post type.

Another thing is: in the backend (i-e: view post links), WP is correctly getting the permalink as desired */events/webinars/post-title-in-webinars* But this doesn't work on frontend (404).

Plus: there are no plugins/tools/etc. installed.

---

Comment: when you say "Here the slug of CPT-A is the base for all other CPTs slugs" can you be more specific? By slug did you mean `cpt-a`? or do you mean the slug of a post that is of type `cpt-a`? There are no examples of full URLs in your question that would make this easier to understand, can you edit your question to include some? Using concrete examples instead of abstract PT names would help greatly too. Also using a tool such as rewrite analyser will reveal rewrite rule/permalink clashes and order problems

Comment: I added an update section with more clarification. Let me know if I need to clear it more.

Comment: thanks that helps! Using your example, and rewrite rule analyser can you check to see if the URL `/events/webinars/post-title-in-webinars` is interpreted as you expected, or, is it interpreted as an event with the slug `webinars/post-title-in-webinars`? Bonus points if you can include screenshots of rewrite rule analyser, testing for this would confirm or rule out that the order of the rewrite rules is a problem here